# Vim, split windows breaks length highlight

Tags: linux, vim

I set this up in my .vimrc to highlight a line over 80 characters.

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkred ctermfg=darkred guibg=darkred
match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
```

Now then, if I open (one buffer) a file with lines that are too long, they'll highlight. Fine, but if I open a different file and then use NERDTree to open a vsplit of the original file, the long line will no longer highlight. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using gvim on GNU/Linux.

Edit: After you open the original file in a split long lines will not highlight FOR ANY FILE until you restart vim and open the file in a single buffer.

Comment: Matches are window-specific.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding here, but as long as you don't open a split, you can open any file and the highlighting still works. Open a split and then everything breaks.

Comment: That's because the split window doesn't have any matches set on it. Matches are window-specific.

Answer (score 8):

The `:match` command only applies to the *current window*. So any `:split` won't inherit the highlighting. This is documented under `:help :match`:

> ```
>   Define a pattern to highlight in the current window.
> ```

You can automatically install the matching for *any* window via `:autocmd`:

```
autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * match OverLength /\%>80v.\+/
```

But I'd recommend to switch to the `'colorcolumn'` setting, which is available in Vim 7.3+; this only highlights a single column (and also in shorter lines), but you can simply `:set colorcolumn=81` in your `~/.vimrc` and it applies to all windows, and you get to keep the `:match` highlighting for other uses.

Comment: if he (like i do) doesnt want to highlight all lines, and only want to highlight the lines wich are too long he could use the `matchadd()` function like this: `hi OverLength ctermbg=darkred  guibg=darkred` `call matchadd('OverLength', '\%>80v.\+')`

Comment: @linluk: Good input about highlighting only long lines; I missed that in my answer. Unfortunately, `matchadd()` is window-local, too, so it also would require the `:autocmd` (but keep `:match` free for use).

Comment: You are right, i just looked it up in the help, `Defines a pattern to be highlighted in the current window (a "match").` I rarely use windows, except for Gundo plugin, Nerdtree, ... so i have not thought about this. but combining it with an `autocmd WinEnter` should do the job. (maybe considering `matchdelete()` to avoid double adding matches)

Comment: maybe you could add this to your answer: 
`augroup mymatches
  au!
  au WinEnter * call clearmatches()
  au WinEnter * call matchadd('Overlength', '\%>80v.\+')                                    augroup END`

Comment: This answer saved my day. Looked everywhere, and as usual, answer at the docs.